# Storing username in session PHP?

Tags: php, session

I am pretty new to PHP Development. So far I stored in a cookie a hash ( user + password ) to keep the user logged in.Now I have discovered php sessions.

Is it possible for someone to modify the value stored as this without having access to server of course?

```
$_SESSION['username'] = 'test@test.com';
```

Comment: I thought only if your code allowed for code to be run, or you had globals turned on.

Comment: Yes there can be some javascripts which can get all your cookies and session data and can modify it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, session can not be modified directly without server access (Until you left loopholes for hacking)

Session is an array on server (RAM or FileSystem) which is mapped to the user through cookies. User only get session id in cookies. When user return, PHP gets that session id and restore session.

Comment: The server data is stored in the file system, not (necessarily) in RAM

Answer (score 2):

The client is never going to change the variable `$_SESSION`. I also recommend you not saving the password in `$_SESSION` and less in `$_COOKIE`. You can check if the user and password are correct and then you can create the `$_SESSION['userID']` or `$_SESSION['user']` and then you just check if the session has been created by creating an if statement with the isset function like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
   // do something...
}
```